# Ограничениe на количество запросов в Flickr API

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.

Пишу приложение для Android, в котором используется что-то вроде google images: человек вводит запрос, появляется список из картинок, тем самым предоставляю пользователю возможность самому выбрать картинку. Для скачивания бесплатных картинок использую flickr.com и их Flickr API. Дело в том, что стоит ограничение на 3600 запросов к серверу с одного личного ключа в час. Одна картинка - один запрос к серверу, так? Стало быть, если один человек прогрузит себе очень много картинок, то доступ заблокируется. Если много людей подключится, то произойдет то же самое.

Видел и другие сервисы, но там 5000 запросов, что тоже не много.

Прав ли я? И как можно обойти это ограничение? Или мне придется выкручиваться как-то, например ограничить один запрос 10 фотографиями?

Comment: Не более 30 картинок за раз можно получить

Comment: Почему 30? Указано ли это в документации?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один запрос это один запрос. Запрос может быть на получение списка фотографий или только одного фото или получение комментариев к фото. Давно не лазил по API Flickr, но мне кажется можно одним запросом вытаскивать несколько фоток сразу.

Можно подать на получение коммерческого ключа к их API там нет ограничений.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, я запутался. Сначала я делаю запрос на flicker.com, который по умолчанию возвращает 1 страницу со 100 фотографиями(т.е. 100 url). Далее при помощи Picasso я загружаю их по этим url в свое приложение. Является ли загрузка в Picasso запросом? Т.е. делаю ли я 101 запрос к серверу в таком случае? Или же только первое обращение к серверу за списком считается запросом, а обращение за картинками не считается?

Comment: Если в урле нет ссылки на ваш API key то это не запрос к API

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Очень помогли.)